# Is it possible to update an attribut within a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Let say that I create an object and run it in a thread, something like this.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeClass p = new SomeClass (143);
    p.start();
    p.updateNumber(144);

}}
```

Is it possible to update the parameter passed in SomeClass with a methode updateNumber() as fallows:

# Updated

```
class SomeClass extends Thread {
     volatile int number ;
     SomeClass (int number ) {
         this.number = number ;
     }

     public void run() {
         while(true){
          System.out.println(number);
           }
     }

  public  void updateNumber(int n){     
          number =n;
          }
  }
```

Result :
144
144
144
144
144
...

Thanks

Comment: This probably requires synchronization of a possibly synchronized method, or otherwise interprocess communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other option not mentioned and which is the option you should use instead of synchronization as mentioned above is the make use of the Concurrency package introduced by Doug Lee in Java 1.5.

Use the Atomic classes, these take care of all you concurrency woes. (well to a point)

Something like this:

```
 private AtomicInteger number = new AtomicInteger(0);

 public void updateNumber(int n) {
   number.getAndSet(n);
 }

 public int getNumber() {
   return number.get();
 }
```

[Java 1.6 AtomicInteger JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

[Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/)

> In my opinion the Java Concurrency in Practice is the best book on threading in Java

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need to declare `number` as [`volatile`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_Java), or ([preferably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968011/volatile-keyword)) use an [`AtomicLong`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) instead of a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

Declare **number** as `volatile`.

When is volatile needed ?

> When multiple threads using the same
>   variable, each thread will have its
>   own copy of the local cache for that
>   variable. So, when it's updating the
>   value, it is actually updated in the
>   local cache not in the main variable
>   memory. The other thread which is
>   using the same variable doesn't know
>   anything about the values changed by
>   the another thread. To avoid this
>   problem, if you declare a variable as
>   **volatile**, then it will not be stored
>   in the local cache. Whenever thread
>   are updating the values, it is updated
>   to the main memory. So, other threads
>   can access the updated value

Comment: I think volatile is not sufficient here.  A `long` is 64 bits long and on a 32-bit machine updating it takes two (non-atomic) operations, so you could end up with a messed up value with the low and high bits from different values.  You should `synchronize` the setter method or use an `AtomicLong`.

Comment: Synchronization is essential here. But, you have to declare the variable as volatile to make it sure that the value will be the most recent one

Comment: **Update**: I checked the latest JLS and a write for a `long` declared as `volatile` is indeed an atomic operation, so your initial suggestion is OK... no need for extra synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

`SomeClass` even it is Runnable, it is just a normal class and objects of it *can be accessed by any thread that has reference to it*. In your example. you are not calling `updateNumber()` form anywhere, but if you call it after p.start(), you are acessing it from the thread that actually made the instance. If you are calling `updateNumber()` in `run()`, then you are accessing it from the thread you've just started.

The other question is: is it safe in your setup to change it form multiple threads? the answer is no. You have to declare it as `volatile` (let say), or `synchronize` if you changing it based on current value. *How and what to synchronize depends on what you are actually doing with it.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyword `volatile`when all the following criteria are met:

- Writes to the variable do not depend on its current value, or you can ensure that only a single thread ever updates the value
- The variable does not participate in invariants with other state variables
- Locking is not required for any other reason while the variable is being accessed

Otherwise, I'd recommend using some sort of synchronization policy

```
class SomeClass implements Runnable {
    private Integer number;
    SomeClass (int number) {
        this.number = Integer.valueOf(number);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
           System.out.println(getNumber());
        }
    }

  public void updateNumber(int n){
      synchronized(number){
          number = Integer.valueOf(n);
      }
  }     

  public int getNumber(){
      synchronized(number){
          return number.intValue();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Moh, if only a single thread (in this case, the main thread), invokes `updateNumber`, then using the keyword `volatile` will suffice. :)

Comment: But in the result, why the value 143 didn't appear? It started directly with 144, I even put a sleep befor the sysout

Comment: @Moh, you'll need to synchronize on the read as well. See my edit with the `getNumber()` method.

Comment: It's not a good idea to synchronize on `number`, especially when you're reassigning its value _inside of a block that's synchronized on it_. A good alternative is to use a separate object, e.g. `Object lock = new Object(); ... synchronized(lock) { ... }` or just make the methods themselves `synchronized`. But _really_, just use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @Matt Ball, I completely agree and I'm glad you made this comment. I was really just trying to show @Moh that the reading/writing of `number` needed to be synchronized or at least atomic. In the past, I've found that using the atomic data types still require synchronization depending on the situation...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just call `p.updateNumber(...)` but you will need to be careful of thread synchronization issues.